# .htaccess URL rewrite to match symbols, letters and numbers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite this URL:

```
localhost/classifieds/index.php?page=activate&extra=$2y$10$LsV9m8JgEz2zMaJYRNqocuOzaqR8oHmn3tBIjIQv.TI4JWd3rWVrC
```

to:

```
localhost/classifieds/activate/$2y$10$LsV9m8JgEz2zMaJYRNqocuOzaqR8oHmn3tBIjIQv.TI4JWd3rWVrC
```

Now, the first part is successful, if I enter:

```
localhost/classifieds/activate
```

it gives me:

```
localhost/classifieds/index.php?page=activate
```

Hereby, loading the right controller.

My major problem is that I want the rule to also rewrite the second part of the URL.

I tried different regex combinations, but all to no avail.

Comment: Would this help? `RewriteRule ^classifieds/activate/(.*)$ index.php?page=activate&extra=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`. LE: I usually let the PHP application route dynamically everything, manage which controller is instantiated if it exists at all. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]` Programmatically split the URL into controller, action and params

Comment: Thank you very much. I modfied your answer a bit and it works. This is what I used finally `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1&extra=$2`

Answer (score 0):

In order for `classifieds/activate/whatever` to silently hit the `index.php?page=activate&extra=whatever`, you need something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Match the host, if you wish
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$

    RewriteRule classifieds/activate/(.*) index.php?page=activate&extra=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In case you want any query string parameter to be passed, you need to add the [`QSA` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to the end of the rewrite rule.

You can test it online, if you wish.

If you need a more generic rewrite rule to rewrite the second segment of the URI (`activate` in this case) to the `page` parameter, here's what you need:

```
RewriteRule classifieds/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&extra=$2 [L]
```

You can be more specific about what characters you want to expect; swapping `(.*)` with something like `([0-9A-Za-z])` or `(\w)` to accept only alphanumeric values will do.