# URL Rewriting // PHP ?q=$1

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, url-rewriting, apache2

I am trying to rewrite

```
www.domain.com/php/roxy/roxy.php?q=ndrapqZrk5StrqiPzNCgn9DGYsal0ZN4nK_UktTFcayo0g
```

to

```
www.domain.com/roxy/ndrapqZrk5StrqiPzNCgn9DGYsal0ZN4nK_UktTFcayo0g
```

I have referenced [StackOverflow - URL Rewrite to Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404671/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-match-symbols-letters-and-numbers)
but couldn't get it working. The .php is called via action="/php/roxy/roxy.php" which then adds the q=[variables] extension

As of right now, going to /roxy url-rewrites to /php/roxy/roxy.php

Comment: What's your current solution?

Comment: I do not have one.